# How can I sum a field from a grandchild table in a LINQ to DataSet where clause?

Tags: c#, orm, linq-to-dataset

I think I need to do exactly this, but instead using LINQ to DataSets because the "Transactions" table is in DB2 and there is no data context.

[Linq query across three levels of tables to generate sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813285/linq-query-across-three-levels-of-tables-to-generate-sum)

I setup two DataRelations on the DataSet:
1. relate Categories (ds.tables[0] in my example) to Products (ds.tables[1])
2. relate Products to Transactions (ds.tables[2])

```
var query = from x in ds.tables[0].AsEnumerable()
    orderby x.Field<int>("Priority")
    select new {
        Name = x.Field<string>("Text"),
        Amount = //maybe using GetChildRows here???
    };
```

I don't really know what to do about the amount. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear whether the records you want from the Transactions table are loaded in ds or they are only in the database.  Even if they weren't loaded you could still make the DataRelation in the database. If they *are* loaded, then it should be pretty easy to do.  If they are not, things are going to get stickier.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion. Everything is loaded in DataSet. Categories and Products are in SQL Server db while Transactions comes from DB2. My other idea was to load the DB2 into a temporary table in SQL Server and use LINQ to SQL, but I figured this would be simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows you need in the Transactions table are loaded in ds, then I think you could do this:

```
DataRelation relationToProducts;
DataRelation relationToTransactions;    
var query = from x in ds.tables[0].AsEnumerable()
orderby x.Field<int>("Priority")
select new {
    Name = x.Field<string>("Text"),
    Amount = x.GetChildRows(relationToProducts)
            .Sum(product => product.GetChildRows(relationToTransactions)
                    .Sum(tx => tx.Field<decimal>("Amount")))
};
```

Comment: I will be testing this shortly.

Comment: Works perfect with the DataRelation constraints. However, I think I've found another potential caveat. Adding the constraints throws ArgumentException if my Transactions records do not ALL have corresponding parent values. My Transactions table may have records that do not have corresponding parent values in Products. So, maybe using DataRelation and GetChildRows is not the best idea. Should I ask a new question?

Comment: Fixed: there is another constructor for DataRelation(string, datacolumn, datacolumn, bool) where the bool (createConstraints) can be set to false.

Comment: Any idea how I could do this without the DataRelation? I'm not sure of the syntax without GetChildRows("relation")